# Problem with run app flutter on bluestacks

Tags: java, android, flutter, visual-studio-code, bluestacks

I'm trying to program Flutter using VS Code and use the BlueStacks Android emulator, but I'm encountering constant errors. I was told to install Java 8, which I did, but then I got an error in the terminal asking me to install Java 11, so I did that too. However, now I'm getting the following error. I would like to know how to resolve this error and be able to debug my Flutter app on the Android emulator using VS Code.

ERROR:

Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 33 in `C:\Program Files\licenses`
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 33 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task `':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'`.

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
> emulator Android Emulator
> patcher;v4 SDK Patch Applier v4
> build-tools;30.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3
> platforms;android-33 Android SDK Platform 33
> tools Android SDK Tools
> To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
> All licenses can be accepted using the sdkmanager command line tool:
> sdkmanager --licenses
> Or, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#download-with-gradle

Using Android SDK: `C:\Program Files`

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: You need to accept the license text before you can use it. Have you tried to start Android Studio or the Android SDK manager? Your title is a bit misleading as it is not related to BlueStacks emulator as building the app already fails, so the used emulator is irrelevant.

Comment: @Robert, i'm sorry, but the tittle is not a misleading, because i dont know if the problem is with the emulator or the app. I only included it in the title because it's what I'm trying to use. I will look into the license. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install and accept all license. And Android SDK components, including Android SDK Platform 33, Android Emulator, SDK Patch Applier v4, and Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3.

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Make sure that the environment is correct and then restart the vscode and run the program again.

*Note: Please use the latest version of [**Flutter**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter) and other extensions and ensure that JDK, JAVA_HOME and other environments are correct.*

Answer (score 0):

There is a related setting `java.jdt.ls.androidSupport.enabled` in the **settings**.

[image]

Specify whether to enable Android project importing. When set to **auto**, the Android support will be enabled in Visual Studio Code - Insiders. Note: Only works for Android Gradle Plugin **3.2.0** or higher. Defaults to auto.

Currently, only the function of reading codes is provided, and more functions are still waiting to be improved.